# Asp.Net Core Redirect To Another Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After completing the update, I am trying to inform it with a warning message and redirect it to another page. It does not redirect after receiving the notification message.

```
                [HttpPost("Home/Edit/{id}")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
           /*bla bla bla*/
            Response.WriteAsync($"<script language=javascript>alert('successfully updated');</script>");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify how and where you call this `Edit` endpoint? And why not pass a flag indicate if the update is successful and then check that flag on client side to alert a specified message?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to page another area.

```
return RedirectToAction("action name", "controller name", new { area = "area name" });
```

Or without another area. just use.

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

But I guess in this instance return `RedirectToAction(nameof(List))` is the same as `return RedirectToAction("List")` see this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof).

Answer (score 0):

You should not write to the response and then redirect to a separate action. This way your view is not going to properly composed.

Try to create a ViewComponent to fulfill your requirement.